# Создание одинаковых объектов с использованием интерфейса

Tags: java, интерфейс

Столкнулся с проблемой создания объектов с использованием интерфейса.
Допустим у меня есть класс Car.

```
class Car extends CarObject implements Rideable {
  public Car(int maxSpeed, ID id){
     super(maxSpeed, ID id);
  }
  public SomeOtherMethod(){}
  public AnotherOne(){}
}
```

Абстрактный класс для всякой всячины:

```
public abstract class CarObject{
protected maxSpeed;
protected ID;
   public CarObject(int maxSpeed, ID id){
      this.maxSpeed = maxSpeed;
      this.id = id;
   }
   public abstract void SomeOtherMethod();
   public abstract void AnotherOne();
   ...
   getters/setters
   ...
}
```

Enum для перечисления существующих ID:

```
public enum ID {
 SlowCar(),
 FastCat();
}
```

И интерфейс:

```
public interface Rideable{
public SomeOtherMethod();
public AnotherOne();
}
```

И список куда заносятся автомобили:

```
 LinkedList<CarObject> object = new LinkedList<CarObject>();
```

И метод для добавления, допустим в классе `Handler`

```
public void addObject(CarObject object){
this.object.add(object);
}
```

Мне нужно создать несколько объектов с одинаковыми параметрами и засунуть их в список:

```
private Handler handler;
private Rideable basicCar = new Car(100, ID.SlowCar);
handler.addObject((CarObject) basicCar);
```

Почему при создании объекта подобным образом, при его повторном создании таким же способом `handler.addObject((CarObject) basicCar);` он не создается, как будто мне мешает встроенный синглтон.
При создании объекта подобным образом:

```
handler.addObject(new Car(100, ID.SlowCar));
```

такого не происходит, объект создается и заносится в список как и должен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это -

```
handler.addObject((CarObject) basicCar);
```

не *создание* объекта. Это занесение существующей ссылки в список.

Это создание объекта:

```
private Rideable basicCar = new Car(100, ID.SlowCar);
```